# How to transform a matrix into a list but keep the row and column identifiers in excel or R

Tags: list, matrix, label

I have a matrix that has two rows and two columns as identifiers which I need to keep in to do further analysis, I can turn it into a list with only one row and one column labels but not with both labels per row and column

[This is part of the matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2ooh.png)

[This is what I need as a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCiTe.png)

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

I tried this
longData<-melt(matrixnew)
longData<-longData[longData$value!=0,]

And got this [I can do it with the dates or second label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5XO7.png)